# mms:// Microsoft Media Server (MMS) on Ubuntu

Tags: server, microsoft

I am trying to experiment the mms:// protocol on linux. Not necessarily I need to stream any media but I like to see the request query logs, headers, etc from a client.

Basically, I have an html tag in test webpage like this:
`<asx version="3.0">
 <entry>
  <ref href="mms://my_ubuntu_server:port/test.wmv"/>
 </entry>
</asx>`

Is it possible to implement such a protocol in linux environment?

Thank you,
Niz

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about an mms://, but here is on streaming media server option under Linux:

**MediaTomb**
MediaTomb is an open source (GPL) UPnP MediaServer with a nice web user interface, it allows you to stream your digital media through your home network and listen to/watch it on a variety of UPnP compatible devices.
http://mediatomb.cc/

I think you can also pay for [Twonky](http://twonky.com/) which runs on Linux and [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) has the ability to stream content as well, but that may be more than what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will have much success, instead consider VLC

[VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

snippet:

```
Features
Simple, Powerful and Fast

Plays everything, Files, Discs (DVD, CD, VCD, Blu-Ray), Webcams and Streams

Plays most codecs with no codec packs needed:
MPEG-2, H.264, DivX, MPEG-4, WebM, WMV player

Completely Free, 0 Spyware, Ads or User Tracking

Works on most platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Unix...

Media Converter and Streamer
```

You need to check that a universe mirror is listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying `mediatomb`,`ums`, `minidlna` , I have found `ushare` to be effective and works well with DLNA as well.  It shows up on DLNA player, VLC as upnp, and local network; which is also discoverable by Windows Workgroup as well.

Streaming responses are bullet fast, and all videos play accordingly exactly line where you press on the timeline at any place inside the clip.

Impressive and implemention is easy.  you only need to configure only one file /etc/ushare.conf.  Then..BAM! You are set to run server within minutes.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ushare/